# Model content doesn't get saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Note` and its attributes are `subject` and `content` the problem is that when creating a new note, the content becomes `nil`.

models/notes.rb

```
belongs_to :user

scope :english, lambda { where("note.subject = ?",  "english") }
scope :math, lambda { where("note.subject = ?",  "math") }
```

controllers/notes.rb

```
def new
  @note = current_user.notes.new
  respond_with(@note)
end

def create
  @note = current_user.notes.new(note_params)
  @note.save
  redirect_to user_note_path(current_user.id, @note)
end

private
 def set_note
   @note = current_user.notes.find(params[:id])
 end

 def note_params
  params.permit(:content, :subject, :user_id)
 end
```

The parameters after submit /notes/new form

```
 Parameters: {.."note"=>{"content"=>"new note"}, "subject"=>"english", "commit"=>"Submit", "user_id"=>"1"}
```

notes/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @note]) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>

    <%= f.label :subject %>
    <%= select_tag(:subject, options_for_select(["english", "math"])) %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit"%>

<% end %>
```

Comment: When you say "content become nil" content attribute is saving nil or all attributes are saving nil?

Comment: content attribute is saved as nil

Comment: Please post your form code

Comment: See the edit, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, using a `form_for(@object)` form_builder will "namespace" all the fields under `object`, which is why you are suggested to use `params.require(:note)`, so as to pick all the fields namespaced with `:note`

In other words, there is a difference between

```
<%= f.select(:subject, options_for_select(["english", "math"]))
<%= select_tag(:subject, options_for_select(["english", "math"])) %>
```

Using `f.something` will namespace under `:user`

Using `something_tag` will NOT namespace

So to completely fix your code with best practices, you should use

```
<%= f.select(:subject, options_for_select(["english", "math"]))
```

in your form and

```
params.require(:note).permit(:content, :subject, :user_id)
```

in your controller

**EDIT** : by namespacing, I mean rails will generate HTML tags like this :

```
<input id="note_content" ... name="note[content]">
```

Instead of

```
<input id="content" ... name="content">
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to rectify your `note_params` function like this:

```
def note_params
  params.require(:note).permit(:content, :subject, :user_id)
end
```

Edit:

You are simply using `select_tag`; this way, this data doesn't get associated with `note` in `params`. You need to do `f.select_tag` as a quick fix for this.

But if you insist on using `select_tag`, then you need to add `note` in your code in the following way:

```
<%= select_tag('note[subject]', options_for_select(["english" ,"math"])) %>
```

Comment: Neither it should. There is some problem with your `form`. `subject` should be for `note` key, but that isn't the case in your posted code.